# cannot link ffmpeg libraries for my own Qt project

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, static-linking

EDIT:  Question solved (see bottom)

I have spent MANY hours searching for a solution to my problem, but have not managed.  I am on OSX and trying to link ffmpeg to my own Qt project.  I have tried to do the simplest thing possible but even this does not work:

After gettings yasm and x264 installed, I ran
./configure --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 and then
make && make install

ffmpeg runs fine when I then try to run it on the command line.  I then just set up a simple project in the ffmpeg directory with the following ffmpeg.pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += core

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lpthread -lbz2 -lm -lz -lx264

HEADERS += ffmpeg.h

SOURCES += ffmpeg.c
```

I'm not sure whether I need all those libraries, but they were all the .a files that ffmpeg created.  When I try to build the project (as is), I get the following linker error:

g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o ffmpeg.app/Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg ffmpeg.o   -F/Users/dtamayo/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -L/Users/dtamayo/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lpthread -lbz2 -lm -lz -lx264 -framework QtGui -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -L/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -F/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -framework QtCore 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_audio_sync_method", referenced from:
      _write_frame in ffmpeg.o
      _do_audio_out in ffmpeg.o
  "_audio_volume", referenced from:
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_cmdutils_read_file", referenced from:
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_configure_filtergraph", referenced from:
      _decode_audio in ffmpeg.o
      _decode_video in ffmpeg.o
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_copy_tb", referenced from:
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_copy_ts", referenced from:
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_debug_ts", referenced from:
      _write_frame in ffmpeg.o
      _do_audio_out in ffmpeg.o
      _do_video_out in ffmpeg.o
      _decode_video in ffmpeg.o
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_do_benchmark", referenced from:
      _ffmpeg_cleanup in ffmpeg.o
      _main in ffmpeg.o
  "_do_benchmark_all", referenced from:
      _update_benchmark in ffmpeg.o
  "_do_hex_dump", referenced from:
      _check_keyboard_interaction in ffmpeg.o
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_do_pkt_dump", referenced from:
      _check_keyboard_interaction in ffmpeg.o
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_dts_delta_threshold", referenced from:
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_dts_error_threshold", referenced from:
      _do_video_out in ffmpeg.o
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_exit_on_error", referenced from:
      _write_frame in ffmpeg.o
      _do_subtitle_out in ffmpeg.o
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_exit_program", referenced from:
      _sigterm_handler in ffmpeg.o
      _assert_avoptions in ffmpeg.o
      _abort_codec_experimental in ffmpeg.o
      _write_frame in ffmpeg.o
      _do_audio_out in ffmpeg.o
      _do_subtitle_out in ffmpeg.o
      _do_video_out in ffmpeg.o
      ...
  "_ffmpeg_parse_options", referenced from:
      _main in ffmpeg.o
  "_frame_bits_per_raw_sample", referenced from:
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
      _avcodec_open2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _avcodec_decode_subtitle2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
      _avcodec_open2 in libavcodec.a(utils.o)
  "_init_simple_filtergraph", referenced from:
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_ist_in_filtergraph", referenced from:
      _decode_audio in ffmpeg.o
      _decode_video in ffmpeg.o
  "_options", referenced from:
      _main in ffmpeg.o
     (maybe you meant: _ff_mpv_generic_options, _ff_rawvideo_options , _av_set_options_string , _ff_rtsp_options )
  "_parse_loglevel", referenced from:
      _main in ffmpeg.o
  "_parse_time_or_die", referenced from:
      _parse_forced_key_frames in ffmpeg.o
  "_print_error", referenced from:
      _write_frame in ffmpeg.o
      _process_input in ffmpeg.o
  "_print_stats", referenced from:
      _print_report in ffmpeg.o
  "_qp_hist", referenced from:
      _print_report in ffmpeg.o
      _check_keyboard_interaction in ffmpeg.o
  "_register_exit", referenced from:
      _main in ffmpeg.o
  "_show_banner", referenced from:
      _main in ffmpeg.o
  "_show_usage", referenced from:
      _main in ffmpeg.o
  "_stdin_interaction", referenced from:
      _transcode in ffmpeg.o
  "_uninit_opts", referenced from:
      _ffmpeg_cleanup in ffmpeg.o
  "_video_sync_method", referenced from:
      _write_frame in ffmpeg.o
      _do_video_out in ffmpeg.o
      _transcode_init in ffmpeg.o
  "_vstats_filename", referenced from:
      _ffmpeg_cleanup in ffmpeg.o
      _do_video_out in ffmpeg.o
      _do_video_stats in ffmpeg.o
      _flush_encoders in ffmpeg.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: Leaving directory `/Users/dtamayo/Desktop/ffmpeg-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Debug'
make: *** [ffmpeg.app/Contents/MacOS/ffmpeg] Error 1
14:35:42: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project ffmpeg (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'

---

EDIT:

---

Thank you very much for your quick responses. I'm embarrassed to say that with the help of a friend I found the problem, so I'll add the solution here in case there are others as inept as I am that run into the same issue!

The problem is that I hadn't added the following source files to the project, which do not get built as part of one of the ffmpeg libraries:

cmdutils.c ffmpeg_filter.c ffmpeg_opt.c

In addition, I had to add usr/lib to my library path, and add the library -liconv.

Answer (score 0):

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'

Did you install your Qt on /tmp and it got after a reboot autodeleted? I am not an OSX user, so this platform might work differently than I think, but it nowhere looks good when the linker tries to access folders, which don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your source code. When you #include the headers you must wrap them in extern "C" {}. With out this, the linker tries to link using c++ function mangling.

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```